# Schengen visa followed by student visa in Germany

Tags: schengen, study

Schengen Visa says that you can visit Schengen states for 90 days over a period of 180 days (6 months) using that visa.

My situation is bit complicated. I will be going to Germany during mid-June for an interview in a German university, and therefore, I need a Schengen visa starting from June. 
If selected, I will have to join as a student at October which will overlap the duration of 6 months from June.

My question is, will I get a student visa starting from October easily, even if it interfere with the period of Schengen visa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering it myself since I went over the entire situation.

It's simple - Schengen Visa and German National Visa (for student in my case) are different and independent. The consulate will not consider the rules of Schengen visa when you apply for a National Visa. It means if you fulfill all the criteria of getting National Visa, get all the mandatory documents and apply for the National visa properly, you will get the visa based on the selection criteria of the national visa. The rule for Schenge Visa won't be taken in consideration at all (which is probably the only logical thing to do).

I applied for the German National Visa for Student after getting Schengen Visa, as mentioned in the question, and got it without any problem. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

I would not say that getting a student visa is “easy” (I would expect quite a bit of bureaucracy) but the earlier Schengen visa should not be a problem. Legally speaking, short-stay Schengen visas and long-stay national visas are very different, for example the 90-day limit and the requirements laid out in the Schengen regulations (insurance, financial means) do not necessarily apply to the latter. If anything, having used visas lawfully before should be a good thing in the eyes of the consulate as it shows you are someone who follows the rules and is not seeking to immigrate illegally at the first opportunity.

Once you have a long-stay visa or residence permit in Germany, you can also visit other countries in the Schengen areas (technically you must still fulfill the usual short stay conditions – no more than 90 days in any 180-day period, justify the purpose of the trip, etc. – but obviously without border checks inside the area all this is not strictly enforced). If the German authorities are bothered by the overlap, they could therefore also easily revoke their own Schengen visa as you wouldn't need it anymore. So that's another reason not to worry.

Also note that not all Schengen visas allow 90-day stays. If it's your first Schengen visa ever, you will most likely receive a visa for the duration of your trip plus 15 days so it will be long expired when you start school in October. Visas for 6 months and more are usually issued to people who have already been in the Schengen area and can justify a need to travel regularly. The 90-day limit is mostly relevant for these multiple-entry visas with a long validity and for people who can visit the Schengen area without a visa. First-time visitors typically get single or double entry visas that are even more restrictive than that.

Finally, depending on your citizenship, [you might need to return to your country of residence to apply for the student visa](http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/DE/Infoservice/FAQ/VisumFuerD/08-Studentenvisum.html?nn=350374). Most people can't do that from within Germany (e.g. while visiting on the Schengen visa). There is an exception for a handful of nationalities (e.g. US or Korean citizens) but those are also countries whose citizens don't need a Schengen visa in the first place so presumably it does not apply to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on travelling for the interview in June, going back home and then arriving again in October - no, I do not think that having the Schengen visa will affect applying for the student visa.

In my experience, it is not difficult to get a student visa if you have been accepted into a course and have enough funds to support yourself. They will also understand that you have to attend the interview to be accepted for the course. Do you have a letter of invitation or anything that you can include in your application documents?

However, if you are planning on staying in Germany between your interview and starting your course, you will need to apply for an Aufenthaltserlaubnis.

This really depends on where you are from and what kind of agreements exist between your country and Germany.

My citizenship allows me to spend 90 days in the Schengen zone in a six month period, without needing to apply for any kind of visa.

A couple of years ago I arrived in Germany in mid-May and was to start my exchange semester in September or October, so I had to apply for an "Aufenthaltserlaubnis" (essentially, permission to stay in Germany but not to work) to bridge the period between my 3 months of stay in the Schengen zone and when my student visa would start. There were multiple bureaucratic hurdles and it was frustrating, but I did get the visa in the end.

My tips are the following, though they might not apply to you if you have to leave Germany to apply for your student visa (the possibility mentioned above):

- contact your local German consulate or embassy and explain your situation and see what they say.
- Make sure you have enough money saved to prove that you can support yourself. This will most likely be a certain amount per month, and probably also enough money for a return flight.
- Check what kind of bank account you will need to put this money in. I had originally opened an account with Sparkasse, but the authority I had to apply for the visa through wanted me to open an account with Deutsche Bank.
- Leave yourself plenty of time to deal with all the red tape and try not to get too stressed out if it is an annoying process. As long as you leave yourself enough time, you should be fine.

Good luck and viel Spass in Deutschland!